# leaflet L.Control Overlay

Tags: leaflet, javascript-objects, overlay

As a newcomer to javascript and the use of leaflet I'm unsure which subject this should be.
Using the Layer Groups and Layers Control example as a model I wish to assign the Control text to the overlays from a variable.
Inserting the variable name simply uses that as text.
Code I've used follows.

```
    var cities_title_0="cities(N-S)"
    var cities_title_1="cities(E-W)"
    var overlays    =   {cities_title_0: cities_layer[0],cities_title_1: cities_layer[1] };
    L.control.layers(null,overlays).addTo(map);
```

How can I get the value of the variable in the control and not it's name please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously (<= ES5) you would have to proceed in 2 steps:

1. Initialize the object `var overlays = {}`
2. Assign your computed key: `overlays[cities_title_0] = cities_layer[0]`

Answer (score 1):

One way is to put the variable name in [] - eg

```
var cities_title_0="cities(N-S)"
var cities_title_1="cities(E-W)"
var overlays    =   {[cities_title_0]: cities_layer[0], [cities_title_1]: cities_layer[1] };
L.control.layers(null,overlays).addTo(map);
```

Comment: For reference, this was introduced with ES6 / ES2015 and is called [_computed property names / keys_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Comment: Thanks, so,simple (now I've been shown). Worked for me. Link mentioned educated me further.